# Software Center Internal Error - Astrill VPN install

Tags: 12.10, software-center, vpn, error-handling

Just installed Ubuntu 12.10 today. Downloaded the "astrill-setup-linux.deb" file from the Astrill VPN website after being directed there by tech support. Go to open it and get an "Internal Error" message.

Has anybody had this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and solved it. Astrill depends on another package that is not automatically installed. For future people visiting this page, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
sudo dpkg -i astrill-setup-linux64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install it `sudo dpkg -i astrill-setup-linux.deb`

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem was the file; incomplete so I downloaded from one of their mirrors.

Comment: so you finally have solved it .